# Help with Identifying Missing Part Due to Unauthorized Removal

Tags: part-identification

All,

A part was removed from underneath engine block of my neighbor’s 1987 Ford Ranger XLT that was parked in his driveway by an unknown person, and we can’t seem to identify the missing part. Here is a photo of the part in an unknown person's right hand. The missing part was removed from the bottom of the engine block, or front suspension area of the vehicle.

However, the identification of the missing part requires further detective work because we've had no success so far from looking underneath the vehicle, and reviewing a parts schematic of the vehicle to determine what was removed. Does anyone have an idea what this part is? Your help is much appreciated!

AWLG

[image]

Comment: Why did you not ask the person removing the part? You were close enough to get a photo...

Comment: This was taken from my ring doorbell camera-- there is a full video of this person's before and after actions. His intent is unequivocal. He doesn't know he's being video taped, and assumes no one is around. He gets on his belly, and removes the item (that's in his hand) from underneath the engine block, etc. and then places the part in his hat, and puts his hat on as he walks off my neighbor's property. We can't identify what part he removed from the truck, so that's why I am asking here!  Does anyone know what could be the part?

Comment: Post better pictures on social media and see if he gets recognised..

Comment: If he gets on his belly rather than his back he's most likely picking something off the road underneath the truck than pulling something off the truck itself.

Comment: How long did it take him to remove it?

Comment: Unfortunately this is going to be opinion based as the picture is not of enough quality to be able to make a factual determination.

It is also speculatory that something was removed off of the truck and was not something that may have been blown/rolled/kicked etc. under the truck inadvertently. We have no proof for or otherwise.

Comment: Nope, he was on his back for 30 seconds, or more, and the video shows him pulling this part from the bottom area of the engine block. And he was not retrieving anything from underneath the vehicle -- please read carefully above. If he did, then no issue. Clearly not the case here! I am not concern about the person doing this deed. All I am asking is if anyone has any idea what was removed, and the only description I have of what that part may be is shown in the person's hand in the picture I posted. That's all.

Comment: Also, no speculation here, or assumptions made, the video is self evident!  I am just paraphrasing what is actually shown in the video; otherwise, I would post the video here if I could!  Also, in the picture, you do have a good view of the outline of the part, and is recognizable if your familiar with area of where the part was removed -- look closer!

Comment: I can't think of anything that could be removed in 30 seconds without any tools from that area.  Is it possible this was some sort of device that someone had placed there previously and this guy is removing?  I'm thinking of a magnetic GPS tracker or similar.

Comment: Who is that masked man........

Comment: "look closer", so we can see... an even blurrier image? Don't be snarky when you are asking for help.

Comment: Not being snarky here! I am just trying to point out, if you look closely at the photo I posted here, there is enough definition to determine the shape of the part, and it’s identification; otherwise, I wouldn’t have posted the question.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, All I see in the picture is a black object. There is not enough definition to definitively conclude what it is. This is why I got rid of my Ring Cameras and got better cameras because the definition of them were horrible. For all we know, it could have been a GPS tracker put there by him or someone else... Did you have a Hide-a-key? I'm not trying to be unhelpful here but we don't have any /GOOD/ information to work from. He could be putting stuff on your truck and using you as a hapless mule. The quality of the photo/video is insufficient to make an accurate determination.

Comment: For an 80's Ranger, there isn't anything I can recall that size that can be removed so quickly unless it was put there by someone deliberately or already loose to begin with. What's your history with this neighbor? Have they been watching you come and go? Do you notice them frequently visit your yard? What you're not understanding is this is not easily quantifiable and all answers will be speculatory. No respectable mechanic would look at this picture and tell you what it is because there isn't enough detail to glean that information. It looks like a black cylindrical object and nothing more.

Comment: Can you add some photos of the underside of the car in the area he was tampering - then we might be able to see if anything is missing.

Comment: The person knew what he was looking for. I review my ring camera footage in front of my house on a continuous basis. Nothing nefarious from my neighbor with regards to his vehicle, or I would have pick up on it long time ago. I was betting someone here would have intimate knowledge of the Ford Ranger and recognize the part, but it doesn’t seems the case. Still hoping!

Answer (score 1):

Find a mechanic with experience working on this model vehicle. Have that mechanic put this vehicle up on a lift. Inspect carefully from underneath, with enough added light for full illumination.

If a part has been removed, there'll be a clean (or cleaner) place where the removed part had been. Similarly, if part had been added (perhaps a tracking device), the added part will be much cleaner than the rest of the undercarriage.

Let us know what you discover.

Comment: ... no markings showing any changes after removal, and no it’s not a tracking device either.

Comment: The object in the man's hand in the video capture is an inch or two across. Were something this size removed, you'd see marks or clean spots in the undercarriage. With respect, that they don't appear points to the conclusion that _no part was removed_.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like some type of elbow hose. Maybe from radiator. Something like this could probably be removed rather quickly.

[image: elbow hoses from google]

Comment: And there'd be a big puddle of coolant on the ground...the pic shows the truck at the foot of the driveway, blocking another vehicle, so it (the truck) is (or was) probably driveable and thus full of coolant. Besides which, old radiator hoses are frequently very difficult to remove.

Comment: so maybe not radiator. still looks like a hose to me,

Comment: Who knows? I like the tracking device scenario.

Comment: The vehicle is drivable, and starts, so no pools of fluid underneath vehicle after removal of part.